# Azure DevOps REST API Perform Git Merge

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to merge a branch using the NodeJS SDK for the Azure DevOps REST API.

I have the following typescript code using the Azure DevOps Node SDK (https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-devops-node-api)

```
  // get master commit
  const masterRef = (await gitApi.getRefs(repository.id!, devOps.projectName, 'heads/master'))[0];

  // merge branch into master
  let merge = await gitApi.createMergeRequest(
    {
      comment: 'Merge',
      parents: [branchLatestCommitId, masterRef.objectId!]
    },
    devOps.projectName,
    repository.id!
  );
```

And I can see in the console when I print the result of the merge object (with a status of 3, indicating Completed):

```
Object
comment: "Merge"
detailedStatus: {mergeCommitId: "faaeb4adef7640d9dac56592ef96e2535dd46078"}
mergeOperationId: 38
parents: (2) ["67f62907ec3ab10afc8452a649bf010e02d38af9", "8ac25ac12c7e9b28195aa64ed7a23d3939a3491d"]
status: 3
__proto__: Object
```

Alas...nothing has changed in my git repository. The branch is still there, unmerged into master.

Comment: Do you mean the REST API was executed successfully, but the branch was not merged? is it? So, are the commits on the branch merged into the target branch? Can you see the commits from the merge branch on your target branch?

Comment: Correct - I see no indications that the merge was actually performed when I look at the git repository. And further that “mergeCommId” doesn’t even exist in the repository

Comment: Thanks for your quickly reply. Are you executing the above code in the pipeline or in the local?

Comment: Locally using a node app

Answer (score 2):

@Jeff  I found  aditional steps (without documentation) to complete the merge process. After createMergeRequest you need to get mergeCommitId with [get merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/merges/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) and update you branch with [update ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/update-ref?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) and you mergeCommitId

Sample code:

```
 const mergeRequestCreate = await git.createMergeRequest(
    {
      comment: "Merge develop into staging",
      parents: [develop.commit!.commitId!, staging.commit!.commitId!]
    }, project, repo.id!)

  await sleep(10000); //need sleep to wait azure process the merge

  const mergeRequest = await git.getMergeRequest(project, repo.id!, mergeRequestCreate.mergeOperationId!)

  const updateRefs = await git.updateRefs([{
    name: 'refs/heads/staging',
    newObjectId: mergeRequest.detailedStatus!.mergeCommitId!,
    oldObjectId: staging.commit!.commitId
  }], repo.id!);
```

Other way is create an PR and complete:

```
 const pr = await git.createPullRequest({
    sourceRefName: 'refs/heads/develop',
    targetRefName: "refs/heads/staging",
    title: 'Merge develop into staging'
  }, repo.id!);

  const commitsPR = await git.getPullRequestCommits(repo.id!, pr.pullRequestId!, project);

  if (commitsPR.length <= 0) {
    const abandoned = await git.updatePullRequest(
      { status: PullRequestStatus.Abandoned }, repo.id!, pr.pullRequestId!, project);
  } else {
    const completed = await git.updatePullRequest(
      {
        status: PullRequestStatus.Completed,
        lastMergeSourceCommit: pr.lastMergeSourceCommit!
      }, repo.id!, pr.pullRequestId!, project);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Git Api, instead...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.githttpclient?view=azure-devops-dotnet

Comment: that **is** the node SDK for the git api....it calls their git REST api....

Comment: Yes... I was comparing it to what was stated in the first line of the original question "Azure DevOps REST AP"  which has url's of the form  https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/ 

For "Git operations" (such as commit, merge, et. al.) I do not (personally/professionally) using that particular API, instead finding the afore mentioned Git API or even shelling out to a command line (there are actions which are *not* taken when using any of the API's in the "obvious" call that do occur when using the commandline (I have been burned by this multiple times).